# How do I create an empty file (0 byte size) in all the directories?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

Recently I was asked, in a job interview, "how to create a zero size file [I think that means an empty file] in all the folders of the file system?"
I found the question a bit strange, I thought of a loop to list all the directory and use `touch` or maybe go to the root directory and use `touch` with a recursive option. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your ideas look good and are a good starting point!

Comment: That question is strange in that it's asking for something completely useless. That said, it's not at all strange for an interview question in that it's asking for something completely useless.

Comment: There are certainly more useful cases for this than @ikkachu thinks. 
For instance, a git template directory structure. 
Git just handles files, not directories, which just come as kind of a "side-effect" of file paths. Therefore, having at least one file in each directory is a must to have otherwise empty directories make it into a git repo.
There are certainly more real-life use cases for such a requirement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That could be ...

```
find . -type d -exec touch {}/emptyfile \;
```

- `-type d` means "directories"
- `exec`ute the command `touch`  and create a file named "emptyfile"
- the `{}` substitutes what is found  as a result from `find`. The `/` is to make it a valid path+filenane and the escaped ; is to close the command (otherwise it becomes "emptyfile;")

result ...

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/t$ mkdir 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/t$ ls -ltr */*
ls: cannot access '*/*': No such file or directory
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/t$ find . -type d -exec touch {}/emptyfile \;
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/t$ ls -ltr */*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 5/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 9/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 1/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 8/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 3/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 2/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 10/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 7/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 6/emptyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 apr 16 19:57 4/emptyfile
```

---

Mine works but the answer from Peter Cordes is better :)

Comment: I was curious if we can speed this up with `-exec ... +` in GNU find.  No, `{}/emptyfile` isn't supported with `+`, only `;`.  So you'd want `find -print0 | xargs -0` to avoid starting a `touch` process for every directory in the FS (which is presumably a lot, and if you're lucky some of the IO will be contiguous and might not be a bottleneck.)

Comment: (I posted an answer with `find -printf | xargs -0` that only has to run touch once per ARG_MAX files created.)

Comment: Awesome answer! Would you mind explaining what you mean by "the escaped ; is to close the command"? What if you leave the semicolon out?

Comment: @TheUnknownDev: Then `find` would complain that there was no end to the `;`-terminated or `+`-terminated series of args that follow the `-exec`.  Try `find -exec echo '{}'` in a test directory.  You need to tell it whether to batch args onto one command, or run the command separately for each file, by using `+` or `\;`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks :D Oh and good one on your answer. I will -not- alter mine as that would be me changing my answer to yours ;-) I assume TS will remove the accepted answer and accpets yours,

Answer (score 9):

To do this efficiently, you want to avoid spawning a new `touch` process for every file you want to create.

This is part of what `xargs` is good for, batching args into chunks as large as possible, while small enough to fit on the command line of a single process. (Modern Linux has pretty huge limits so it's rarely a problem anymore, xargs rarely has to actually run your command multiple times to handle all the args, but it also lets you avoid having filename subjected to shell word-splitting like in `foo $(bar)`.)

We can use find's own `-printf` to format additional stuff onto each directory path, specifically the filename we want.  The `xargs -0` uses a `'\0'` byte as a separator so this is safe with arbitrary filenames, even including newline.  If you weren't using a custom printf format, you could just use `-print0` to print 0-separated paths.

```
  find . -xdev -type d -printf '%p/empty\0'  | xargs -0 echo touch
```

(in a test directory, that prints `touch ./empty ./2/empty ./1/empty`, not `touch ./empty`,  `touch ./1/empty`, etc. so it's running one `touch` for multiple files.)

`mktemp` only accepts a single template, but if we want *some* randomness in the naming to reduce the chance of just touching an existing file by accident, you could do this.

```
  find . -xdev -type d -printf "%p/empty.$RANDOM\0"  | xargs -0 echo touch
```

Note that it's the *same* 15-bit random number in every directory, because `"$RANDOM"` is expanded once by bash before find starts.  You could use `$(date +%s).$RANDOM` or whatever you want as part of the filename.

---

With an SSD or tmpfs, CPU might be the bottleneck here.  Or if you're lucky and metadata I/O on a magnetic disk happens to be mostly contiguous because you're touching *every* directory (and allocating a bunch of new inodes), even a rotational disk could maybe keep up somewhat decently.  Although you're probably not touching directories in the order they're laid out on disk.

And regardless, there's no need to waste lots of CPU time starting processes for something that should be I/O limited.

---

**Ways that don't work:**

- `find -exec touch {} +` batches args, but `-exec touch {}/empty +` refuses to work when `{}` isn't by itself.
- `xargs -I {} echo touch {}/emptyfile` implies `-L 1` (only process one "line" of input for each invocation of the command, whether that's an actual line or a 0-separated string with `xargs -0`).  So we can't use xargs to modify each arg if we want to take advantage of it for batching args.

Answer (score 7):

```
find /mountpoint -xdev -type d -exec mktemp -p {} \;
```

A quite obvious aspect is you may or may not need root access to actually create files under `/mountpoint`.

There are two non-obvious aspects:

1. You said "in all the folders of the file system", so we start from specific `/mountpoint` and do not enter other filesystems (`-xdev`).

   If there are other filesystems mounted deeper in the tree, e.g. in `/mountpoint/foo/another/mntpoint`, then `-xdev` will prevent us from entering them. Still these filesystems may mask entire subtrees that belong to the filesystem in question. In the best case a filesystem mounted in `/mountpoint/foo/another/mntpoint` masks an empty `mntpoint` directory of the filesystem in question. So we cannot easily reach "all the folders of the file system".

   With root access we can `mount --bind /mountpoint /somewhere/else` beforehand. With `--bind` (as opposed to `--rbind`, see `man 8 mount`) `mntpoint` deep in `/somewhere/else` will not replicate the submount from `/mountpoint/foo/another/mntpoint`. This way we can access `mntpoint` that belongs to the filesystem in question.

   This is still not enough. If the filesystem in question is Btrfs then *possibly* `/mountpoint` gives access to some subvolume but not to the entire filesystem (compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1396245/432690)).

   In general a subtree of any(?) mounted filesystem can be bind-mounted to another directory. After you unmount the original mountpoint, the other directory gives access to a fragment of the filesystem. Our `/mountpoint` may be "the other directory" in the first place and therefore it may not give access to the entire filesystem. You don't know this in advance.

   The conclusion is: if the phrase is strictly "all the folders of the file system" (as opposed to "all subdirectories" which is quite straightforward) then you need to make sure you don't miss any part of the filesystem. Only then use the `find …` command given at the beginning of this answer.
2. Solutions with `touch emptyfile` or so do not necessarily "create a zero size file". What if the interviewer has already created a non-empty `emptyfile` in one of the directories? A trap! If non-empty `emptyfile` exists then `touch` will neither create it, nor the file will be empty. Effectively you will strictly fail to "create a zero size file" in the directory with the trap. This is the reason I used `mktemp`. The tool will try hard to really create a new empty regular file.

Answer (score 3):

This will create a **unique name** empty file in each directory **starting** with and **descending** from the current directory including **hidden directories** if you want to.

**First**, get the directories list with `tree`.

**Then**, pass them to `xargs` like so:

```
tree --noreport -dfi | xargs -L 1 -I {} echo touch {}/emptyfile_"$(date +%s)"
```

**Or**, to a `while` loop like so:

```
tree --noreport -dfi | \
while read -r d; do echo touch "$d"/emptyfile_"$(date +%s)"; done
```

**Or**, even to a `for` loop (if the directory names contain no spaces) like so:

```
for d in $(tree --noreport -dfi); do echo touch "$d"/emptyfile_"$(date +%s)"; done
```

- `echo` is there to prevent unintentional creation of files while testing. When satisfied with the output, remove `echo` to create files.
- `--noreport` omits printing of the file and directory report at the end of the tree listing.
- `-dfi`  lists directories only, prints the full path prefix for each directory and makes tree not print the indentation lines.
- Use `-dfia` instead of `-dfi` to include **hidden directories** as well.
- `"$(date +%s)"` appends current timestamp to filename like this `emptyfile_1618679443` making it unique from existing files in each directory. Notice you can change this to a random number like `67639871206723` if you need a fixed file name.
- `xargs -L 1 -I {}` reads the input one line at a time and assigns it to `{}`.

Comment: Can't you use `find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to let it pass multiple args to each invocation of `touch`?   Seems to me if you're going to use xargs instead of `find -exec`, avoiding one process startup per directory would be good.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is possible like so `find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} echo touch {}/emptyfil` and there may be other possible ways as well... but `find` is already discussed in the other answers. I wanted to shed some light on `tree` which is a remarkable tool with great potential... Just for diversity sake. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: xargs `-I` options apparently implies `-L 1`, unfortunately, running touch once per arg.  (Apparently a 0-separated string counts as a "line").  And `-I {} -L 1000  echo touch {}/emptyfile` doesn't work either, it prints `touch {}/emptyfile . ./2 ./1` if run in a test directory.

Comment: @PeterCordes I got what you mean the first time :) ... It would be nice if it works that way... but, ARG MAX might be reached easily for the OPs purpose and touch needs some format like `touch {1/,2/,3/}emptyfile` to address multiple directories and then ARG MAX  awaits

Comment: Part of xargs's job is to break up input into arg-max chunks.  But apparently only if we don't need xargs to modify each arg.  Finally came up with a solution using `find -printf` to add stuff to each pathname: `find . -type d -printf '%p/emptyfile\0'  | xargs -0 echo touch`

Comment: Wrote that up as an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes It is worth an answer and you earned my **upvote** :)